# Error Running createsuperuser in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I have a Django project, that's already been deployed. I'm using a virtualenv for the project and have installed django in it. I have activated the virtualenv.

When I type `pip freeze` I get:

```
Django==1.7.1
django-jalali==1.1
django-multiselectfield==0.1.3
jdatetime==1.3
```

But when I try this command: `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` I get the following error:

```
(.env)benyamin@i-bmn:/srv/bmn-reg$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
(.env)benyamin@i-bmn:/srv/bmn-reg$
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's your default python? is it 2.X? If it's so and you want to use `python3` you need to install your requirements with pip3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whethere `pip` is using `python3` by issuing the following command:

```
pip -V
```

You may need to use `pip3` or `pip3.x` to install packages into Python 3.x environment if `pip` is using Python 2.x.

**UPDATE**

You're using `virtualenv`, you should use `python` (which references proper python executable), not `python3` (probably references system version of python 3.x).